# Can blood flow destroy part of the metal stent in 10 to 40 years?

Tags: medications, blood-circulation, cardiovascular-disease, venous-system, stents

If a part of the metal stent has not grown into a vessel, can this part of the stent be washed out by the blood flow in **10 to 40 years (theoretically)**?

Also are such cases known that blood flow destroy part of the metal stent in **10 to 20 years (practically)**?

For example, titanium + nickel (self-expanding stent).

**Clarification:** Metal stents can corrode/dissolve, but this process is uneven, so some parts of the stents can dissolve earlier, and some later — then these parts break away from the stent and float to the heart and lung (if this part of the stent has not grown into a vessel)

**Question:** I clarified the question: what percentage of the different types of effects contribute to stent fragmentation: vessel pulsation, mechanical bending, blood flow?
What percentage (1%, 10%, 90%) of stents breaks down into fragments from mechanical stress (arterial pulsation, ...), and what percentage (1%, 10%, 90%) of stents breaks down into fragments from blood flow (corrode/dissolve) **after 10-40 years**?

---

For example, stents broken into several parts:

- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6342613/

> Computed tomography (CT) image showing fracture of right coronary
>   artery (RCA) stent into three fragments

- Images with broken stents: https://www.ahajournals.org/doi/10.1161/CIRCINTERVENTIONS.113.000148

[image]

Comment: I've never heard of a coronoary or other arterial stent being broken apart by blood flow, other than erosion of the drug-eluding stent coating perhaps.  A stent is basically a mesh tube... Where is your source for this?

Comment: @DoctorWhom  I just know that over time, stents break down, as do kava filters. If arterial stents are destroyed possibly due to cardiac pulsation. What could be causing the cava filter or Venous Stent to break, is it not a blood flow?

Comment: @Alex Stents can fail, but they don't literally break down. The usually fail either because they didn't deploy properly in the first place or they become obstructed by the body's healing response. Vena cava filters are similar. They can migrate (rarely), but the metal doesn't break down.

Comment: @Carey Gregory♦  Kava filters can be destructed and their parts enter the heart and lungs. One cava-filter was destructed after 4 days [101].  101. Chitwood W.R., Chiang K.S., Williams J.M. et al. Embolectomy of a Bird’s Nest vena cava filter // The Annals of Thoracic Surgery. 1994. Vol. 58 (6). P. 1766–1768. https://doi.org/10.1016/0003–4975 (94) 91687-x.

Comment: Also 25% of cava-filters was broken down into several fragments after 5 years [102] 102. Nicholson W., Nicholson W.J., Tolerico P. et al. Prevalence of fracture and fragment embolization of bard retrievable vena cava filters and clinical implications including cardiac perforation and tamponade // Archives of Internal Medicine. 2010. Vol. 170 (20). P. 1827–1831.https://doi.org/10.1001/archinternmed.2010.316.

Comment: Fragments of CF from the branches of the pulmonary arteries, as a rule, cannot be removed [108] 108. Baik P., Fourzali R., Salsamendi J., Salerno T. Transventricular migration of an inferior vena cava filter limb // The Annals of Thoracic Surgery. 2014. Vol. 97 (1). P. 343. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.athoracsur.2013.04.113.

Comment: Yes, the arms on a filter can fracture, but the metal doesn't literally dissolve.

Comment: @Carey Gregory♦  But what is the reason for the destruction of filters and stents?

Comment: @CareyGregory Metal stents *can* corrode a bit, and some of the metal literally does dissolve. The corrosion makes them more susceptible to fracture, which of course will occur before they completely disappear. Alex...I'm kind of unclear what you are asking, though. I was going to write an answer but I would be citing similar sources to the ones you've posted in comments. What sort of answer are you looking for?

Comment: @BryanKrause I don't doubt they can corrode a bit, and fracture is well documented, but the question seems to ask about literally dissolving, and that they don't do.

Comment: @BryanKrause, I believe the confusion is with wording. The Q initially sounded like if metal can "dissolve" or something. Now the OP has clearly shown that mesh stents can "break," so the construction, not the metal itself brakes. The stents can also dislodge and move. Aleks, I believe you can improve the question by asking if there are known risks associated with certain types of stents.

Comment: @Jan Yeah, that's why I asked for clarification. Maybe the actual intended question is "what causes stent fracture?" but the attempt at a guess made its way to the question, leading to confusion (sort of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))?

Comment: @Bryan Krause I believe it could be a good question (and answer) to discuss if there are any predictable risks for various types of stents regarding breaking - to make all this practical. Like, which stents break more - if there is any statistics about this.

Comment: @Jan There certainly are, but since fractures are relatively rare events and because there aren't likely any controlled trials large enough to compare rates between stent types, it's hard to read too much into them, except for obvious technical risks like jailbreaking. Still, I think it's best to wait for OP to clarify their question before trying to answer.

Comment: I clarified the question: what percentage of the different types of effects contribute to stent fragmentation: vessel pulsation, mechanical bending, blood flow ?